# Avoid automatic replacement of << characters

Tags: fonts, symbols

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
a << b
\end{document}
```

When compiling, the two "`<`" characters get replaced by a single "opening french quote" character (sorry, don't know its name).

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour (besides using math mode) ?

**Edit**: I know I can get around with `a $<<$ b` or (as suggested in comments) with `a {<}< b`, or with verbatim mode. My question can be rephrased as:

**Is there a way to tell Latex NOT to do these automatic character replacements?**

**Edit2**: Use case: I am putting up some course text documents on OSes, and appending to a file gets written `a >> b`.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the ligature always or only in some cases?

Comment: Well, I am curious about the general case: I know Latex does this sort of things behind the hood, I'd just like to know if I can drive this behaviour myself (turn on/off).

Comment: Well, `a {<}< b` certainly would get around the ligature.

Comment: Sure, so does `$<<$`, but this doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Well, considering that both Ulrike and I weren't sure whether you were looking for a one-off or a global solution, perhaps you should edit your question to clarify exactly what you are looking for.  Remember, we don't necessarily have a sense of your experience level with LaTeX.

Comment: looks like you are looking for some verbatim rendering, hence try `\verb@a <<b@` or in a `verbatim` environment.

Comment: Clarified question. It's just... a question, perfectly ok for me if answer is just NO, I just want to know ;)

Comment: What's the semantics/purpose of `<<` here?

Comment: @jfbu Or listings (or any other package that provides a good semantic indication of the usage) as pointed out by gerw.

Comment: For the record: practically, the solution that I use in such a context (besides using listings, which can be cumbersome for just a 3 words example) is in the answer proposed by @egreg. Side comment: the problem described here is similar with `--` (bash long options). So I use `-{-}`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want it globally you can use microtype:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[<]{encoding = T1}
\begin{document}
a << b
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, never used that package, just learned something today!

Comment: Since the user (@kebs) says (s)he has never used the `microtype` packages, I think it would be useful to add a notice to clarify that loading it affects the typesetting well beyond the sheer fact of making it possible to suppress ligatures.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I still hope that users at least skim a few pages of the documentation before using an unknown package.

Comment: Your hope is waaaay too optimistic ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Then they deserve what they get.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I only do that if something breaks quite visibly after adding the package.

Comment: ok, feel safe ;-), I'll `texdoc microtype`. A bit (241 pages... gasp!).

Comment: Accepting answer, as it is the closest to the question, although I might not actually use it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Fair enough. :-)  Mine was just a suggestion for a possible improvement to your answer.

Comment: @T.Verron  If I see an unknown package I always do a short check of the documentation. I look at the date and when it has been last updated, at the author (trustworthy or not?, still active?), at the introduction (to get an idea what the package does), and also at the size. Imho the five to ten minutes spent for this check are worth it, one can avoid a lot of troubles if one has an rough idea about the content of every package used by a document.

Answer (score 19):

For locally disabling the ligature you have several methods:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
a << b

a <{}< b

a {<}< b

a <\/< b

a <\textcompwordmark< b

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer the one with `\/`, because it's engine independent; the same example (but with `fontspec`) in LuaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
a << b

a <{}< b

a {<}< b

a <\/< b

a <\textcompwordmark< b

\end{document}
```

would give

[image]

because LuaTeX ignores braces when doing ligatures.

Of course, the best thing is to define a personal command, so you can modify the rendering without chasing the document for `<\/<`:

```
\newcommand\textll{<\/<}
```

and

```
a \textll{} b
```

When somebody will tell you that some negative kerning must be applied between the less than symbols, you'll be happy of having preferred an abstract method.

Side note: this assumes the OT1 encoding is not used; with it the input `<<` would not produce a ligature, but ¡¡ (two reverse exclamation marks); the ligature `<<` for a left guillemet is only active in the T1 encoding (and possibly LY1) and, with `fontspec` and (Xe|Lua)LaTeX, for fonts loaded with the `Ligatures=TeX` option.

Comment: you might comment (re engine independence) that with original knuth tex, the `<` would be rendered as an upside down exclamation point.  the `\/` *doesn't* overcome that.  probably irrelevant for most people these days, but there are still some "holdouts".

Comment: Thanks for answer. Solution 4 & 5 is indeed what I want. And defining a new command does seem a good option.

Comment: Another engine-independent method worth mentioning is the insertion of an explicit kern, e.g., `\kern0pt`.

Comment: @Mico Yes, `\/` is indeed an explicit kern.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the engine isn't really the issue there (you'd get Spanish punctuation by default in (say) xelatex as well, it's the font (and font encoding) that matter so anything using computer modern will do that.

Answer (score 12):

In the comments it was specified that this is actually bash source code. So LaTeX should know that it is bash source code. This can be done be using, e.g., the listings package:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
As listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
a << b
\end{lstlisting}

Inline:
\lstinline[language=bash]{a << b}
or
\lstinline[language=bash]/a << b/
\end{document}
```

Comment: True, and I do use the listings package in many occasions! But listings produces a separate text block, and the idea here is to have it "inline". Thanks for answering, but the question is about the general case.

Comment: And no, not only bash typesetting as use case. It's the same syntax with the Windows shell.

Comment: You can use inline-listings. See the last lines of the answer. And for Windows shell source code the answer is the same ;)

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll check the "inline" listings mode, never used it that way, thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: it seems to me that `\lstinline` can't be used inside a table (`tabular`). Do you confirm ? If true, that is a serious limiting factor.

Comment: It works if you do not use `{}` as delimiters, e.g., `\begin{tabular}{c} \lstinline[language=bash]|a << b|
\end{tabular}`.

Comment: Oh, ok, indeed does fine, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

For the case of math type setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ a \ll b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And with `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ a < b \ll c \lll d \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with amssymb]

Comment: Mmmh, Thanks, but those are not two separate characters.

Comment: @kebs The question misses the context. In mathematics, it's one symbol, meaning "much less than". `a << b` looks pretty like math to me. But, I have written a [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329759/avoid-automatic-replacement-of-characters/329811?noredirect=1#comment808025_329759), asking about the purpose and semantics of the symbol(s).

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misread Edit 1. That's my bad.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Right, thats why I clarified the use case (as a comment first, then as edit2.